# Problem with testing Linux cluster using the Mandelbrot set

Tags: ubuntu, cluster-computing, mandelbrot, mpich

I have a six-node cluster running Ubuntu 11.04 and MPICH2 1.4.  I'm trying to test the graphics using the Mandelbrot set.  The pmandel executable that is supposedly found in one of the MPICH2 subdirectories is supposed to render the Mandelbrot fractal on the screen using all the nodes in the cluster, and all the directions I've found so far tell me to "use the pmandel exec" for this test.  There is no exec - there is only pmandel.c, pmandel.h, and pmandel.pd.  I thought I should compile pmandel.c to create the exec, but I get the following errors when I try:

```
cs_lab@daedalus01:~/MPICH2/mpich2-1.4-source/src/mpe2/src/graphics/contrib/mandel$ mpic++ -c pmandel.c
In file included from pmandel.c:14:0:
pmandel.h:27:8: error: ‘MPE_XGraph’ does not name a type
pmandel.h:35:3: error: ‘MPE_Color’ does not name a type
pmandel.c:27:1: error: ‘MPE_XGraph’ does not name a type
pmandel.c:29:28: error: variable or field ‘DrawImage’ declared void
pmandel.c:29:28: error: ‘MPE_XGraph’ was not declared in this scope
pmandel.c:29:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
pmandel.c:29:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
pmandel.c:29:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
pmandel.c:29:60: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
pmandel.c:30:28: error: variable or field ‘ProcessArgsFromFile’ declared void
pmandel.c:30:28: error: ‘MPE_XGraph’ was not declared in this scope
pmandel.c:30:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
pmandel.c:30:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
pmandel.c:30:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
pmandel.c:30:59: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
pmandel.c:31:28: error: ‘MPE_XGraph’ was not declared in this scope
pmandel.c:31:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
pmandel.c:31:47: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
pmandel.c:31:47: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
pmandel.c:45:15: error: variable or field ‘UpdateDisplay’ declared void
pmandel.c:45:15: error: ‘MPE_XGraph’ was not declared in this scope
pmandel.c:45:33: error: ‘MPE_XGraph’ was not declared in this scope
pmandel.c:45:64: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
pmandel.c:45:65: error: ‘flags’ was not declared in this scope
```

It just looks like standard compilation errors to me.  But why would MPICH2 be released with an error-ridden file?  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I just can't figure out how to run this test.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly just "bitrot" on the code. It's in "contrib" too, which suggests external work included in distribution because it might be useful, but not directly part of the main source distribution

Answer (score 0):

If you configured your copy of MPICH2 with `--enable-mpe` (or, more likely, without `--disable-mpe`), then there should be a `Makefile` in `src/mpe2/src/graphics/contrib/mandel`.  Try running `make` from that directory and see if that will build `pmandel` for you.

With all that said, when I ran the program it worked initially and then segfaulted when I attempted to zoom in by dragging a new box.  YMMV.  As awoodland mentioned in the comments, this is contrib code so the MPICH2 team didn't write it.  The author listed in the README appears to have moved on from Argonne, so you are unlikely to receive any support from him.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your MPE header is empty due to configuration issues. Try this:

```
$ cat <YOUR MPICH DIRECTORY>/include/mpe.h
```

And this:

```
$ cat <YOUR MPICH DIRECTORY>/include/mpe_graphics.h
```

If you see any warning message, you should consider compiling and installing it again from [source](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/downloads/index.php?s=downloads).